# \bigskip or \vspace{5mm} comes in at the wrong place?

Tags: vspace

Everytime I use the command `\bigskip` or `\vspace{5mm}` it doesn't show in at the right place in document. It always comes about a line and a half after, in the middle of sentences. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! It's hard to tell what is going wrong from the description alone. Could you please extend your question to include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/172164) that others can try themselves, and maybe an image showing the output you get?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Apparently you put them on the wrong place. To be more specific, you need to show us an example of short document, which reproduce your problem. BTW, inserting `\bigskip` should be in LaTeX very rare excewption!

Comment: Vertical space is only inserted once in vertical mode. So, if you just place `\vspace` or `\bigskip` somewhere in a sentence, it will only insert that *vertical* space once the horizontal (sentence) lines are constructed on the page in a vertical list. This *will* happen after the place where you insert it.

Comment: Okay, but maybe you guys have an easy way to make a little space between two paragraphs? i use \newline or \\* - but that has to with the \noindent and im writing a big paper (50+ pages) and it seems a little tedious to do it every time i want a little space. because i have to use newline a few times in a row (error?) because the space i want has to be a somewhat big, and not just a single line. 
Any options for this ?

Comment: @MortenMandsberg you should never need to use vertical space, `\noindent` or a `\\ ` until possibly the very final copy-edit stage.  If you want a style with no indent and vertical space between paragraphs that should be set up in the document preamble, using a class designed for that or by adding `\usepackage{parskip}`

Comment: So will that package allow me to write and make vertical space without having to code it?

Comment: if you need to add space for a special purpose (eg to add an image in post-production) , simply leave a blank line then `\vspace{5cm}`  but you should never need to do this for normal paragraph spacing.

Comment: @MortenMandsberg yes the choice between indented pararaphs with no vertical space and unindented paragraphs with vertical space between them is a style choice which should be set once, there need be no change in the document body, just like changing the main document font or page size.

Comment: thanks alot! it did seem a little tedious!